# How to specify multiple boolean comparisons in Perl?

Tags: perl

Is it `while ($x > 3 || $y < 2)` like in other programming languages? I literally can't find anywhere online that tells me how to do this in Perl.

Comment: https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/PERL/node35.html

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=990

Comment: @AbhiNickz that tutorial is incredibly out of date. While the general information is correct, it contains a lot of information that rings my alarm bells. It declares variables without `my`, it tells you it's ok to use strings with the number comparison operators and it uses _PERL_ as the name of the language, which is outright wrong. Please don't use this resource. It's overstayed its usefulness. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I checked again, I just wanted to show OP that there are lots of online resource that I found in just one google search.

Comment: @SangoProductions: Why don't you try it?

Answer (score 3):

Try [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#C-style-Logical-And). There’s both C-style `||` + `&&` available and `or` + `and` with different operator priority.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it while ($x > 3 || $y < 2) like in other programming languages?

Yes it's the same.

Let's put it into an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $x = 10;
my $y = 0;
while ($x > 3 || $y < 2){
    print "X is $x, Y is $y\n";
    $x--;
    $y++;
}
```

Output:

```
X is 10, Y is 0
X is 9, Y is 1
X is 8, Y is 2
X is 7, Y is 3
X is 6, Y is 4
X is 5, Y is 5
X is 4, Y is 6
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/V4GKjb)

Pretty easy, right?